# Moving a row on google spreadsheet based on 1 cell and verifying second cell is not blank

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am fairly new to Google Sheets scripts and I am trying to modify my current script that moves the row from one sheet to another within the same workbook based on a "y" or "n" value in column 20. The new script will still look at column 20 for a "y" or "n" but I want it to also look at column 19 to verify there is a value there. This is my code thus far but it does not work:

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();

  if (s.getName() == "2018 2 Week Snapshot for Jim"
      && r.getColumn() == 20
      && r.getValue() == "y") {
    if (s.getName() == "2018 2 Week Snapshot for Jim"
        && r.getColumn() == 19
        && r.getValue(r.isBlank()) == false) {
      var row = r.getRow();
      var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Reviewed 2018 2 Week Snapshot for Jim");
      var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
      s.deleteRow(row);
    }
  }
  if (s.getName() == "2018 2 Week Snapshot for Jim"
      && r.getColumn() == 20
      && r.getValue() == "n") {
    if(s.getName() == "2018 2 Week Snapshot for Jim"
        && r.getColumn() == 19
        && r.getValue(r.isBlank()) == false) {
      var row = r.getRow();
      var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Reviewed 2018 2 Week Snapshot for Jim");
      var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
      s.deleteRow(row);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @JSmith Here is a link to the doc: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q8NDK3U2wIRxOdn_LK2WvGZbpttYD2A1f4eqYqgpoWw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: is jjjjoe post answering your question?

Comment: @JSmith - Still pending a final solution. I need to insure column 19 is not blank instead of is blank and I am happy to combine the two, I am just not clear how.

Comment: @JSmith Sorry, I am now if you are still free to help.

Comment: added a correction to move all the line `e.source.getActiveSpreadsheet().getLastColumn()` not `e.range.getLastColumn() + 1` if you want to be sure to get the whole row width

Comment: I've edited my answer line 12 of the code.

Comment: @JSmith I apologize but the new code does not work.

Comment: sorry this should work now forgot to put the `()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have "based-on active cell" solution you need to take advantage of the [`e`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) parameter of the `onEdit`event.

check if the range is the one you want to test, then test if the value is the right one, then check the same thing for the other range (column S in this case).

You will after it is checked `moveTo` the range to the destination spreadsheet and delete the moved row.

The code would do something like this:

```
function onEdit(e)
{
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 20)
  {
    if(e.value == "Y" || e.value == "N" || e.value == "y" || e.value == "n" )
    {
      var val = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange("S" + e.range.getRow()).getValue();
      if (val == "Y" || val == "y" || val == "N" || val == "n")
      {
        var destSheetName = "Reviewed 2018 2 Week Snapshot for Jim";
        var destSheet = e.source.getSheetByName(destSheetName);
        e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.getRow(), 1, 1, e.source.getActiveSheet().getLastColumn()).moveTo(destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow() + 1 , 1, 1, e.source.getActiveSheet().getLastColumn()));
        e.source.getActiveSheet().deleteRow(e.range.getRow());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The crux of your issue is that instead of directly getting the ranges you want to look at, you're using the active range (`var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();`) and checking, in two nested `if` statements, whether that range is both on line 19 and line 20, *and* whether that range is both blank and contains something (a "y" or an "n"). In other words, in order to get into your first block of code, the following has to be true:

```
s.getName() == "2018 2 Week Snapshot for Jim"
&& r.getColumn() == 20
&& r.getValue() == "y") {
&& s.getName() == "2018 2 Week Snapshot for Jim"
&& r.getColumn() == 19
&& r.getValue(r.isBlank()) == false
```

Needless to say that's logically questionable :-)

As an aside, `r.getValue(r.isBlank()) == false` doesn't make much sense -- you probably want `r.isBlank()` if you're looking for column 19 to be blank. My answer reflects that, and you should invert that condition if I got it wrong.

I also notice that your actions look identical whether you find a "y" or an "n" in column 20: in either case you're deleting the original row and pasting it in "Reviewed 2018 2 Week Snapshot for Jim." My answer retains the distinction because I assume there's other stuff you want to do conditional on seeing a y/n.

Anyways, this should do what I think you're trying to do (notice all the caveats? :D)

```
function onEdit() {
  var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();  // The range being edited
  var s = r.getSheet();                     // Its sheet
  if (s.getName() != "2018 2 Week Snapshot for Jim") {
    // We're not editing the sheet we're interested in...
    return;
  }
  var activeRow = r.getRow();  // What row number are we on?
  var colNineteenNotBlank = !s.getRange(activeRow, 19).isBlank();  // Or did you need this *not* to be blank?
  var colTwentyValue = s.getRange(activeRow, 20).getValue();
  var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
  var sourceRange = s.getRange(activeRow,    // start this row
                               1,            // start column 1 (A)
                               1,            // range should be 1 row
                               numColumns);  // range should be this many columns
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Reviewed 2018 2 Week Snapshot for Jim");
  var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1,
                                         1,
                                         1,
                                         numColumns);
  if (colTwentyValue == "y" && colNineteenNotBlank) {
    sourceRange.moveTo(targetRange);
  } else if (colTwentyValue == "n" && colNineteenNotBlank) {
    // maybe you wanted something else here?
    sourceRange.moveTo(targetRange);
  }
}
```

This still isn't bullet-proof; if the target sheet fills up I'm not sure that getting a range off the "end" of the sheet will work. If that's common, I'd check that `targetSheet.getMaxRow()` and `targetSheet.getLastRow()` match, and do a `targetSheet.appendRow()` if so.

Comment: I need column 19 not to be blank. Also, column 20 will be blank until they enter a "Y" or a "N". If there is a better way to write this then I would love to learn.

Comment: I edited the condition which checks column 19 by adding a `!` (boolean NOT) -- I also changed the variable name to be truthful and descriptive.